# Is this an efficient way of finding the longest words (plural) in a string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, words

I'm new to Python and found a couple of suggestions for finding the longest WORD in a string, but none which accounted for a string with a number of words which match the longest length.

After playing around, I settled on this:

```
inputsentence = raw_input("Write a sentence: ").split()
longestwords = []
for word in inputsentence:
    if len(word) == len(max(inputsentence, key=len)):
        longestwords.append(word)
```

That way I have a list of the longest words that I can do something with. Is there any better way of doing this?

**NB:** Assume `inputsentence` contains no integers or punctuation, just a series of words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'll be doing this with short amounts of text only, there's no need to worry about runtime efficiency: **Programming efficiency,** *in coding, reviewing and debugging,* is far more important. So the solution you have is fine, since it's clear and sufficiently efficient for even thousands of words. (However, you ought to calculate `len(max(inputsentence, key=len))` just once, before the `for` loop.)

But suppose you do want to do this with a large corpus, which might possibly be several gigabytes long? Here's how to do it **in one pass,** without ever storing every word in memory (note that `inputcorpus` might be an iterator or function that reads the corpus in stages): Save all the *longest* words only. If you see a word that's longer than the current maximum, it's obviously the first one at this length, so you can start a fresh list.

```
maxlength = 0
maxwords = [ ]  # unnecessary: will be re-initialized below
for word in inputcorpus:
    if len(word) > maxlength:
        maxlength = len(word)
        maxwords = [ word ]
    elif len(word) == maxlength:
        maxwords.append(word)
```

If a certain word of maximal length repeats, you'll end up with several copies. To avoid that, just use `set( )` instead of a list (and adjust initializing and extending).

Comment: Great! Really clear explanation, nice suggested edit of my original and a good lesson in clarifying efficiency. Giving an alternative based on the potential constraints of the original code was a huge help. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb

inputsentence = raw_input("Write a sentence: ").split() 

lwords = list(next(gb(sorted(inputsentence, key=len, reverse=True), key=len))[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a `defaultdict` with the length as the key and adapt the following:

```
words = inputsentence.split()
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
for word in words:
    dd[len(word)].append(word)

key_by_len = sorted(dd)
print dd[key_by_len[0]]
```

Comment: Why `sorted` over `min` or `max`, alternatively you could just track the max length to be more efficient

Comment: @jamylak going for the case of 2nd greatest length etc... (or shortest)... And given the use-case a `sorted` is really not going to be that more noticeable than a min/max

Comment: Thanks for the speed Jon. To clarify for somebody who is new to programming, what are the advantages of the method you have described over my own example?

Comment: @user2061277 You're re-calculating the length each time for each word

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
print max(raw_input().split(), key=len)
```